# My code is trying to finding all prime numbers between 0 - nth number, what is the use of '+ 1' within the statement 'bool prime[n + 1];'?

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm new to C++ and is trying to solve the beginner's problem of finding all prime numbers between 0 - nth number. I saw this code online and it works perfectly.

However, my question is what is the use of '+ 1' within the statement 'bool prime[n + 1];'? I have deleted it from the code and everything seems to work just fine. Is it necessary or is it redundant?

```
void SieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {

    bool prime[n + 1];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof (prime));



    for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++) {
        // If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime
        if (prime[p] == true) {
            // Update all multiples of p
            for (int i = p * 2; i <= n; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
        }
    }

    // Print all prime numbers
    for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
        if (prime[p])
            cout << p << endl;
}

int main() {
    int n = 1000;
    cout << "Following are the prime numbers smaller "
            << " than or equal to " << n << endl;
    SieveOfEratosthenes(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The range 0..n contains n+1 numbers. That's the size you need for the array.

Comment: "everything seems to work just fine" That's because you're hitting UB by going off the end of the array.

Comment: if you remove the +1 you will write the last value outside the array boundries. which can cause really bad errors since you write to some memory on stack which no longer belongs to this variable.  (maybe another variable, might even be a pointer which leads to wrong addressing errors...)

Comment: Note that the declaration of `prime` with a non-constant array size is not legal C++ (it is, however, legal C since C99). You are likely relying on a compiler extension here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C++` an array of size `N` have index start from `0` to `N-1`. so for your problem, for `N` index assign `N+1` size array. so that define the primality to `N` number.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ (and many other languages) an array of size n has an index for 0 to (n - 1). In this case, you will need to check each number, up to and including n. You therefore need a spot in the array for n, at index `prime[n]`. This index will only exist if you oversize the array by 1. Otherwise, the array will stop at `prime[n - 1]`.

The reason this works even if you take out the `- 1` is that C++ is not fussy about array bounds - once you have an array you can legally read or write at any index, whether or not that index is safe. Notice I said legally, not safely - this is potentially very dangerous behaviour.

Comment: No, you cannot *legally* read out of bounds. It is just that the compiler does not have to enforce it. Note that the compiler is not *forbidden* to enforce it; while it is normally not done, the compiler is free to add checks; it's just hard to do that, so most compilers don't do it even in debug mode.